# SVG not showing in browser

Tags: svg, browser

I am having problems with my svg's when i view my website on chrome it shows properly but when a view it on other browsers like Firefox, safari and IE my svg's are invisible.Please help Thank you.
This is a sample of one of my svg's.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path  d="M33.4,19.6c-0.6,0-1.2,0.5-1.2,1.1v15.5h-8.2v-6.3c0-0.6-0.5-1.1-1.1-1.1h-5.9c-0.7,0-1.2,0.5-1.2,1.1v6.3H7.7
  v-15c0-0.6-0.5-1.1-1.2-1.1c-0.6,0-1.1,0.5-1.1,1.1v16.1c0,0.6,0.5,1.1,1.1,1.1h10.5c0.6,0,1.1-0.5,1.1-1.1v-6.3h3.6v6.3
  c0,0.6,0.5,1.1,1.2,1.1h10.4c0.6,0,1.1-0.5,1.1-1.1V20.8C34.5,20.1,34,19.6,33.4,19.6z M39.7,20.5l-9.1-9V5.4
  c0-0.6-0.5-1.1-1.2-1.1c-0.6,0-1.1,0.5-1.1,1.1v3.9l-7.5-7.4c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.4c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.4L0.4,20.4
  c-0.5,0.4-0.5,1.2,0,1.6c0.4,0.5,1.1,0.4,1.6,0L20,4.2l18,17.9c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.3c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.8-0.3
  C40.1,21.7,40.1,21,39.7,20.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You should post the main and runnable parts of your code.

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox 45.0b5, IE11 and Chrome 46. What versions are you using?

Comment: Firefox 44.0 and safari 5.1.7. I re-checked the svg's and i dint see anything wrong but what is confusing me is that then what could be coursing the svg's not to be visible when i load them with the site. Its a word-press site, on firefox it shows all the icons in the home page but when i navigate to other pages the svg's are not visible. In safari  non of the svgs are showing even in the home page. but in chrome everything is perfect. #m puzzled

Comment: I checked it with Freifox 38.3.0 ESR and there it works fine, too. But I just copied your code in a separate HTML file. Did you checked if the content (your SVG description) is there? Or did Safari or FF just received an empty file?

Comment: Its there, but not visible

Comment: Could you check the rendered width and height, browsers sometimes give  a svg a weird size.

Comment: The thing is that its in the correct height and width and i can even increase the width of the svg in the console, it will only show the svg get bigger but not showing the icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what helped me to make the svg's to show in firefox.by using Jquery

```
.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//Change url or svg use tags for FF
var useXHREF = function () {
    jQuery('use').each(function (i, url) {
        var id = jQuery(url).attr('xlink:href');
        jQuery(url).attr('xlink:href', window.location.href + id);
    });
}
useXHREF();
```

For Safari on Mac is fine but on windows, it dosint recognise the fill:#... add color:#...... to make the svgs to become visible. Thanks to all for the comments and trying to help.